# Git can't find .ssh

Tags: git, msysgit

Problem using msysgit on Windows; it can't find .ssh/id_rsa, even though it is present where it should be.

I verified that's the problem with ssh -v git@github.com; that command works when and only when I use the -i option to explicitly point it at the correct id_rsa file but as far as I can tell, git itself doesn't have such an option; and I can't find anything either on Google or in the supplied documentation.

The peculiar thing is, it worked fine last time I used git a few months ago, and I haven't changed anything since then that seems a likely cause.

I've tried the following, all to no effect:

- Generating new id_rsa
- Putting .ssh in current directory
- Putting .ssh in root directory
- Uninstalling msysgit and reinstalling the latest version
- Setting the HOME environment variable
- Installing TortoiseGit and trying that instead (didn't work at all)

Any ideas what else to try?

Comment: On linux, at least, ssh will accept `-vv` and `-vvv` to pump up the verbosity - maybe that will tell you where exactly it's looking for the key?

Comment: It does indeed accept those, but the output is the same: it claims to be looking in /.ssh/id_rsa, but it lies (since I did put a copy of .ssh in the root directory, which ssh can read if explicitly pointed to).

Comment: Huh. Why is it looking in `/.ssh/id_rsa` instead of `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`, anyway?

Comment: If I knew that, I'd know more than I do now!

Comment: When you say you set HOME, you mean within the shell, right? And you exported it? (I'm sure you did, I'm just short on ideas like you are - I'm pretty sure ssh just looks in `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` so this really makes it look like `$HOME` is actually empty`...)

Comment: From within the Windows command prompt, yes. I don't know what you mean by exported, but I ran the subsequent ssh test command within the same prompt, so it was within scope of the environment variable.

Comment: I know nothing about windows, but try `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and then try git again.

Comment: ssh-add says "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." regardless of arguments.

Comment: @rwallace: Oh, I was thinking you were trying this in git's bash shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it!

The problem is that there are two different git commands, git.exe (the actual program) and git.cmd (which sets up the necessary stuff for it to work on Windows). Depending on what options you set at install time, you can end up with a scenario where the former rather than the latter is the one that ends up in your path, so it doesn't work. Then the usual debugging suggestions regarding ssh.exe don't work unless you've run git.cmd.

In a nutshell, just make sure you're running git.cmd instead of git.exe.

Comment: And how does one make sure of this?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with git in Msys/MinGW where it couldn't find my private key, despite being able to ssh into the server fine.

The problem was that the entry in `~/.ssh/config` said:

```
Host github.com
IdentityFile /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

However Git required the full path from a Windows point of view like this instead:

```
Host github.com
IdentityFile c:/mingw/msys/1.0/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and then it worked.

To discover this path from msys, run `cd ~/.ssh` and then `pwd -W`

Answer (score 1):

Oddly msysgit has it's own .ssh directory:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh`

Placing your ssh key there should work.  It solved the problem for me

Comment: Is this still the case? Could not find this folder.

Answer (score 0):

The windows way is to [import your ssh key to putty](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/putty-rsa-dsa-keys/) and [use putty agent](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html).

Comment: The linked page says using putty is an option you select at install time, but the latest version of msysgit doesn't give me any such option; has this changed or something?

Answer (score 0):

Our admins changed the `HOMEDRIVE` on Windows and afterwards tools like ssh did no longer find their config anymore. Seems like `HOMEDRIVE` is used as default value for `HOME`.