# Trouble setting up git deployment via PHP on IIS

Tags: php, git, deployment, ssh, iis-7.5

Firstly, this is my first time setting up webhooks and I'm not familiar with Windows servers. I've seen quite a number of posts on this but I still can't resolve the issue - could be due to my lack of understanding on Windows servers and permissions.

I have a Windows 2008 R2, and I want to be able auto-pull via a PHP script after changes are pushed to an external GIT repository.

- The site is setup and works properly. It lives in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename
- This folder is cloned using my Remote Desktop user, which is an Admin. The cloning is done via Git Bash and i understand that the SSH keys lives in the admin's home/.ssh dir.
- This folder is writable by IIS_IUSRS
- I've also copied the keys into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh` as noted here ([Git can't find .ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042482/git-cant-find-ssh))

I have a PHP script in that folder with the 'pull' code:

```php
exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" pull 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output);
echo '--done--';
```

The page just hangs with the loading icon on the browser. There's no output.

But if do 'status':

```
exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" status 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output);
echo '--done--';
```

I'm getting the expected output.

I'm guessing it's could be due to Permission on SSH keys. Running both scripts using Windows CMD (not Git Bash) works though

So my troubles are:

2. I'm not sure if it is the SSH key not being loaded cause I can't see the errors on the browser
3. I'm not sure I even started in the right direction to begin with.

I dare not fiddle further as this is meant for Production.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have stored your git credentials for your current user, but when the web server (IIS_IUSRS) executes the git command, is doesn't have credentials and therefore asks for username and password. This then hangs the script.

You could try:

- <s>pipe the username and password to the process</s> edit: this did not work for me, because git creates multiple sub-processes that are not bound to the pipe.
- put credentials in a _netrc file and save it in the IIS user's home directory (see C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles...)
- Start a console as your IIS user, use a git command and store the credentials using a credential helper for that user.

See here on how to store Git credentials: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Permanently+authenticating+with+Git+repositories

Comment: ok, thanks for this. I'll give this a try as soon as i have time.